# Redirect to the another component in class component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How can I redirect to another component with following code?

I can not use useHistory() because I don't have functional component. Is there any similar way to fix this?

```
class Register extends Component {
state : {
    userList:object[];
} =   {
    userList : [],
}

passwordEl= React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
confirmpasswordEl= React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
emailEl = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
registerUser = () => {
    const { userList } = this.state
    let newUser = [...userList]
    let emailValue = this.emailEl.current
    let passwordValue = this.passwordEl.current
    let confirmPassword = this.confirmpasswordEl.current
    if (emailValue && passwordValue && confirmPassword) {
        if (passwordValue.value === confirmPassword.value) {
            newUser.push({
                username: emailValue.value,
                password: passwordValue.value
            })
            this.setState({userList: newUser})
            alert('Succesfull Registration')
        } else {
            alert('Passwords Must Match')
        }
    }
}
```

These are my buttons :

```
<div id={'buttons'} className="buttons">
                <Link to={'/login'} >
                    <button>Log In</button>
                </Link>
                <button  onClick={() => this.registerUser()}>Register</button>
            </div>
```

My imports :

```
import React, {Component,createRef} from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './Register.css'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should be wrapped with the router from the main top level component.
With that you should be able to take advantage of `history` within your `props`.
If you can't access it, wrap your export of the class with:

```
export default withRouter(Register);
```

Just trying to remember how to access the props in classes, but I believe it would be:

```
this.props.history
```

Then when you want to redirect you would just do:

```
this.props.history.push('/my/new/route');
```

**UPDATE**

```
import { History, withRouter } from 'react-router'; // or 'react-router-dom'

type MyProps = {
   history: History
}

class Register extends Component<MyProps> {
}

export default withRouter(Register);
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention,I tried to follow ur example and typescript gave me this error TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly{}> & Readonly{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Comment: Yeah you'll need to extend the props for the class with the `History` type. See the **UPDATE** section. That said, I would really recommend going with Hooks and Functional Components in the future, if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,I will definetly try